# How can I set up a usb printer as a network printer using a linux server?

Tags: ubuntu, printing

Basically right now I have a USB only printer, it's very nice. There are 5 people in my household and we all are constantly wanting to use the printer.

Windows has a built in way to share the printer, but this only works when the computer is on. I have several low power small machines that I use to run Ubuntu Server Edition.

Is there an existing Linux application that would allow me to basically use the USB printer as if it were a networked printer?

Also I don't know how possible this would be but if there were a way to run the Apple AirPrint server on the Linux box too that would be awesome, then we could all print from our iDevices as well.

Comment: Found this link http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Debian-and-Windows-Shared-Printing.html#sharing_with_windows Going to give it a try and post back with results.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have 2 choices.

#### Wireless USB Bridge

You can either get a little wireless/USB device that will share the printer out via wireless. You then connect to it using IPP such as `ipp://<ip address of wireless bridge>/USB_queue`.

A device such as this would be up to the task: [NETGEAR PS121 USB 2.0 Mini Print Server](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0001BXVA4).

We use such a device where I work. This particular device presents the printer over the network using LPD, so we access the USB printer attached to it like this:

```
lpd://192.168.1.109/L1
```

#### Shared via computer

You can attach the printer to a PC like normal, and then using CUPS share that printer out over the network. Again users can access the printer using IPP such as `ipp://<linux host w/ printer>/<name of printer`.

Additionally if you setup Samba, you can share the printer out using Samba to Windows PCs as well as Linux systems instead of IPP.

#### Sharing the printer

Once you've got the printer detected on a Linux host you can either access the printer configuration GUI from the pull downs or from a terminal:

```
/usr/share/system-config-printer/system-config-printer.py
```

This will bring up the following dialog:

[image: ss of printer dialog]

Here you can see that the USB printer is detected by the lost Linux host and is working correctly:

[image: ss of printer properties]

Now select the "Policies" section and check the shared printer checkbox:

[image: ss of printer sharing]

Now on a client you select the printer like so:

[image: ss of printer dialog on client]

#### References

- [Sharing Printer with CUPS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100528/sharing-printer-with-cups)